# SaveAs without prompt to save

Tags: excel, vba

I have this excel macro with which I make a copy of a file (Newbook), change it and and save the original (Oldbook) under a new name.

However, even though I'm using SaveAs, excel keeps giving me this prompt to confirm that I want to save the original file under the name that I gave it.

I've already tried:

- Oldbook.Saved = True
- SaveChanges = True
- Application.DisplayAlerts = False

None work.

```
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Newbook.Save
    Newbook.Close

    Oldbook.SaveAs Filename:=fNameOld, FileFormat:=xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
    ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

    Oldbook.Close

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the exact message in the prompt? What's the value of `fNameOld`?

Comment: thanks for your reply @Jean-FrançoisCorbett. The prompt is a 'Save as' box, with the right location and name that I made already there, so that you only have to press 'Save'. fNameOld is made with Application.GetSaveAsFilename

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: Yes I see my mistake now, shouldn't have used Application.GetSaveAsFilename! Stupid of me, thanks!

Comment: The only time I get the message to confirm is when there is already a file by the name existing and prompts to overwrite.  Did that comment solve your problem?  If so, please post your own answer.  Otherwise, can you post the code where you get your fileName?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer! The problem was that I used Application.GetSaveAsFilename to make fNameOld, which makes the 'Save as' prompt appear.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything unusual about where you are trying to save the file eg, is it a network location or a sharepoint library?  Any how, try adding these 2 lines after your saveas and before your close

```
Cancel = True
Oldbook.Saved = True
```